# Best way to store a blog post in DynamoDB?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm creating a blog section for a website with Amazon Web Services. I'm comparing database solutions, and I came across DynamoDB. I'd like to know if it'd be a good idea to use DynamoDB for storing a blog post of more than 1500 words (6KB approximately). Should I save the article as a file onto the S3 instead, and store its link on my DynamoDB database? What is the right way of implementation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB is a key-value, NoSQL database that delivers single-digit millisecond performance at scale. It is a fully managed durable database with built-in security, backup and restore, and in-memory caching for internet-scale applications. [More information here](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/).

You can certainly use DynamoDB to build a blog application. You would need to model your data and depending upon the language that you use, you can use a DynamoDB mapper. For example, if you built you application by using the Spring Framework, you can use the [Enchanced Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html).

Assuming you did build with Spring Framework - you could build it very similar to [this tutorial](https://nakov.com/blog/2016/08/05/creating-a-blog-system-with-spring-mvc-thymeleaf-jpa-and-mysql/) and by replacing the relational database with DynamoDB. Using DynamoDB as opposed to reading a file stored in Amazon S3 in my view is the better way to proceed here.